# Laravel localized date formatting (pattern)

Tags: laravel, date, format, tostring, php-carbon

I would like to set Laravel and Carbon so that, based on the current locale selected by the user, dates will be formatted with the correct pattern. I thought it was enough to set LC_TIME on the desired locale and then use the Carbon method **toDateString** to get the correct format but, regardless the LC_TIME setted, it always return a date string in the format yyyy-mm-dd.

Expected results:
 - If Italian selected, then mm/dd/yyyy
 - If English selected, then yyyy-mm-dd
 - and so on

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and Carbon 1.36.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I had the same problem with an old Laravel app and we solved it by storing the format of the localised dates in a separate language file:

**`resources/lang/en/dates.php`**

```
return [
    'full' => 'Y-m-d'
];
```

**`resources/lang/it/dates.php`**

```
return [
    'full' => 'm/d/Y'
];
```

When formatting a date, just use the `config()` helper to fetch the format provided for the language set in `config/app.php`, use `$date->format(trans('dates.full'))` and it will return the proper localised date.

If you so fancy you can use a [macro](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-macro) (which was added in 1.26.0) too, to simplify this process:

```
Carbon::macro('localisedFormat', function ($key) {
    return $this->format(trans("dates.{$key}"));
});
```

and access it via

```
$date->localisedFormat('full');
```

Comment: shouldn't `$date->format(config('dates.full'))` be `$date->format(trans('dates.full'))`?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Imma fix that. Glad I could help you!

Answer (score 5):

```
Carbon::now()->isoFormat('L');
```

Gives you the current standard digit-format date for the current locale (20/5/2020 for "it_IT", 5/20/2020 for "en_US").

And you can customize this format for a given locale in translations:

```
Translator::get('en')->setTranslations([
  'formats' => [
    'L' => 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  ],
]);
```